# Appcelerator - Hide UI element in list generated by dataCollection

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am using Alloy and Alloy Collections to generate a list of views in an app.  I need to be able to hide child elements within each view based on data within the model object.

For example I have a an Alloy view:

```
<View dataCollection="$.collectionOfStuff">
    <Label>Always visible</Label>
    <Label>Only show when {isVisible} is true</Label>
    <Label>Another label always visible</Label>
</View>
```

Assuming the models in `$.collectionOfStuff` has a `isVisible` property, I would like to be able to hide the second label based on that value.  Setting the visible property on the Label is easy enough but this just hides the element and doesn't reclaim the space - meaning there is a gap between the first and third label.  I need the second label to stop taking up space as well.

I have tried using the data binding syntax to add a `hidden` class to the element (`<Label class="{hiddenWhenNotVisible}">`) but Alloy doesn't appear to resolve data binding tags in class attributes.

This doesn't seem like it should be so difficult so I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I don't believe that data binding supports what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visible property like so:

```
<Label visible="{isVisible}"/>
```

Or using dataTransform to set width to 0 and don't ocuppy space on the UI

In the View

```
<View dataCollection="$.collectionOfStuff" dataTransform="transformModel">
    <Label>Always visible</Label>
    <Label width="{width}">Only show when {isVisible} is true</Label>
    <Label>Another label always visible</Label>
</View>
```

In the controller

```
function transformModel(model){
    var data = model.toJSON();
    data.width = !data.isVisible ? 0 : 50;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: It's be nice but that doesn't quite work.  Setting the `visible` attribute on an element hides it from the user but preserves the space the element would occupy if visible.

Comment: alloy is limited, although you can add another property "width" in your model depending if is visible or not you assign width = 0 or the size when showing like <Label width="{width}"/>